# what is "channels" and where it is comming .i am getting this error undefined method `channels' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class ChannelsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @channels = current_user.channels
    respond_with(@channels)
  end

  def new
    @channel = current_user.channels.build
    respond_with(@channel)
  end

  def create
    @channel = current_user.channels.build(params[:channel])
    @channel.save
    respond_with(@channel)
  end

  def show
    @channel = current_user.channels.find(params[:id])
    respond_with(@channel)
  end

  def edit
    @channel = current_user.channels.find(params[:id])
    respond_with(@channel)
  end

  def update
    @channel = current_user.channels.find(params[:id])
    @channel.update_attributes(params[:channel])
    respond_with(@channel)
  end

  private
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(params[:user_id])
  end
end
```

Comment: on which line are you getting it? and please use the code template..

Comment: current_user is nil so when you current_user.channels it throws the error undefined method channels for nil::nilclass

Answer (score 0):

Without a backtrace, I'd guess that `current_user` is `nil`, likely meaning that you're not logged in or that `current_user` isn't behaving as you expect. Try looking into that.